# What happened to the women & children of Shechem who were taken captive by Jacob"s sons in Genesis 34:27-29?

Tags: genesis, jacob

(KJV) Genesis 34:27-29

> 27 The sons of Jacob came upon the slain, and spoiled the city, because they had defiled their sister.   28 They took their sheep, and their oxen, and their asses, and that which was in the city, and that which was in the field, 29 And all their wealth, and all their little ones, and their wives ***took they captive***, and spoiled even all that was in the house

Emphasis added

After the Dinah incident the sons of Jacob attack Shechem & kill every male taking captive women & children.

Nothing is ever said again about these captives for when Jacob moves to Egypt(Genesis 46:27)only his descendants are mentioned.

What happened to these captives?

Comment: I've wondered about this before also.  While most commentators say there's no sure answer, one commentary was interesting.  James Kugel in "How to Read the Bible..." (2007- pp 169-171) says modern theory is that both the birth of Dinah and Shechem accounts may be a 'later additions' - GoogleBooks    https://goo.gl/mzmnWJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18May2018  ...  This is my theory of what happened to the women and children of Shechem after Jacob's son by Leah murdered their men.

Its plausible that after Jacob had a talk with the LORD in Genesis 35:13 that he took on the women from Shechem as his daughters instead of treating them as captives.  If so, then as daughters, they would have been permitted to marry Canaanite men whom the clan encountered during there journey to Bethlehem (Genesis 35:19), to the tower of Edar (Genesis 35:21), to Hebron (vs 27) or may have married Esau's sons listed in Genesis Chapter 36.  Some of them may also have become Jacob's daughters in-law and stayed with the household until Jacob moved into Goshen, Egypt [Reference Genesis 46:7].   I don't think the elderly Jacob fathered any blood daughters besides Dinah.

Thus, its plausible that the daughters referred to in Genesis 46:7, 15 may have been the women captives from Genesis 34:2.